# Javascript : Omitted Initialize inside Nested For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

As we know, we can omit the initialization inside the for loop :

```
var i = 0;
for(; i < 10; i++) {
  // do Something with i
}
```

However, i figure out if i omit the initialization inside the nested loop as well:

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
for(; i < 10; i++) {
  for(; j < 10; j++) {
     // only do Something with j
     // outner loop only run once
  }
}
```

Solution :

```
 var i = 0;
 var j;
 for(; i < 10; i++) {
   j = 0;
   for(; j < 10; j++) {
      // everything is fine!
   }
 }
```

Can anyone explain whats going on? I'm newbie in Javascript.

Comment: when you have initialized j = 0 outside of both the loops. 
Then for i = 0, inner loop will run and then value of j is 10;
After this the value is never initialized to 0, which you did in second case.
And due to which inner loop runs only one time.(Only when i = 0)

Answer (score 1):

The loop runs multiple times, but your 'j' is already ten after the first run of `i`, so the second loop no longer runs during the next values of `i`.

If you would write something like this.

```
  for(; i < 10; i++) {
     for(; j < 10; j++) {
           console.log("test")
      }  
      console.log("another test")
   }
```

You would see that both messages get printed 10 times.

The reason that your "j" loop, only runs "ten times once", is because you do not set J back to zero after it has run 10 times. So the statement `j < 10`is true for every loop if `i`after the first run.

You could solve this by setting `j = 0` inside the first for loop (if you do not want to put it inside the variable initialisation of the second loop.)

```
for(; i < 10; i++) {
    j = 0;
    for(; j < 10; j++) {
        console.log("test")
    }
    console.log("another test")
}
```

Comment: Ah ha! Looks like i have done some simple programming mistake. The outner loop actually runs, just the variable j hit the counter in the first run, so it wont run again in second time. Thanks for the explanation =) !

Comment: @Hunter.Wei no problem! If you want to, you can accept this answer as correct to let other people know that it was correct. (And upvote if you want)

Answer (score -1):

Every time `i` increments, you need to reset `j` to `0`.

If you rewrite your script so that each variable is initialised *within* the `for loop` statement itself, then every time `i` increments, `j` will be reset to `0`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    }

}
```

Comment: The OP knows this, he is asking a question about what happens when we omit the initialisation inside the for-loop. :-)

Comment: I think your answer is better, @DylanMeeus and I have upvoted your answer. But I am not persuaded that the OP knows that _"Every time `i` increments, you need to reset `j` to `0`."_ - because it is precisely not knowing this (or seeing it) which leads the OP to ask their question.

Comment: I think he does, considering the title saying (omited initialise) and the first sentence. but thank you for the upvote! Your answer is the correct answer in case he does *not* know this though!